# Is it possible to edit sale.order workflow in Odoo9?

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

I active developer mode in odoo9. and go to Setting > Workflow > Workflow and can't find sale.order workflow.

after that.I try to edit workflow like odoo8. I go to Sale > Sale Orders > Open Debug Menu > Edit Workflow > Diagram 
[like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBGNz.png)

and I got this message.
[Odoo Warning - Access Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9jNB8.png)

Is it posible to edit core workflow? because I need to change some step when I have sale order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sale.order workflow was removed in odoo 9. So no, it not possible to edit it because it is not there.

Comment: Is there any alternative to being able to edit the sales workflow in odoo 9? We are trying to implement credit limits like the solution posted here : https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/how-can-i-activate-a-credit-limit-for-my-customers-327